# How to qsort a specific column of an array?

Tags: c

I want to qsort a particular column of an array but have to move the other elements accordingly 
For example

```
UNSORTED ARRAY

40 2
30 6
20 1

REQUIRED SORTED ARRAY

20 1
30 6
40 2
```

if it can't be sorted with qsort then please suggest some method which is efficient and doesn't take time just like qsort.
Please And Thank You.

Comment: Why not write some code?

Comment: I did it with insertion sort and it works fine but the time complexity is large.

Comment: lyk if you have 10^5 elements then it won't complete in 1 sec.

Comment: Well depends on the computer

Comment: I am talking about online judge . I have to do a question in one second and the constraints are 10^5 elements which would exceed the time limit if done with insertion sort.

Answer (score 1):

Standard qsort routines always sort array *lines*, and you define a callback comparison function (and pass its address), which is completely under your control.

In that callback function, qsort will pass you two elements (rows) and ask you for comparison, and you return 1, 0, -1 for greater, equal, smaller accordingly. You can in that code compare only the columns you want to sort on (or do about anything fancy you want), and qsort will always sort the whole array lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: you have a `struct` with a key and value pair, build an array of this `struct`, populate the elements as desired and then use a callback function as suggested by Aganju. Thus, you would have an array of `struct`s which are sorted.

Comment: Sorry But I don't understand what you mean to say?